# ¿Como puedo crear un porta papeles de imagenes y audios?

Tags: javascript, php, python-3.x, html5, ccs

Quiero crear una porta papeles osea un botón que al darle click no copie un texto si no una imagen o un audio como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Ana, te recomiendo editar tu pregunta, mostrando el código en el que quieres implementar esto, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: El hecho de que uses muchas etiquetas de diversos lenguajes, me da la impresión de que no escribiste un código. Lo que significa o que pides código, o pides orientación. Te aviso que así no funciona el sitio.